# Unknown column in left join search query like

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for multiple join table and need to search/like in joined table:

```
$this->select('posts.*, languages.name as language_name, users.avatar as user_avatar');
$this->join('languages', 'languages.id = posts.lang_id', 'left');
$this->join('users', 'users.id = posts.author_id', 'left');
$this->like('language_name','English');
$this->orderBy($columnName , $columnSortOrder);
$this->limit($rowPerPage, $start);
$query = $this->get()->getResultObject();
```

but in output i see this error:

```
"Unknown column 'language_name' in 'where clause'"
```

how do fix this error?

Comment: If change to `$this->like('languages.name','English');` , still have error?

Comment: @tcadidot0: work but i need to alias name for dynamic search query.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use "languages.name" instead of "language_name"

You should try to use the table name as prefix sinds you are using joins.
In the underneath example I'm assuming that title comes from the "post" table.
Therefore use "post.title" and the same for language_name, use "languages.name".

```
if($searchValue != ''){ 
   $searchQuery = " (post.title like '%".$searchValue."%' or languages.name like '%".$searchValue."%') "; 
}
```

Comment: this work now, but i need to alias name for dynamic search query data. ie:         `$searchQuery = "";
        if($searchValue != ''){
            $searchQuery = " (title like '%".$searchValue."%' or language_name like '%".$searchValue."%') ";
        }`

Comment: @LaraBell , is the updated answer above working for you?